# save sum of a column as record in other table

Tags: c#, sql

im trying to pass a column sum in other table as a record.

tables i got:

| Order |
| --- |
| order_id |
| sum_price |

| Order_Position |
| --- |
| order_id |
| price |

I have to save the total of the prices with the same order_id from the order_position table in the order table where the order_id is equal to the totaled prices

Comment: which database you using? Also update the question with the problem you having

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description, but that doesn't tell us what _problem_ you're having. What have you tried, and what troubles did you encounter? Please [edit] your post to include a [valid question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know what is [on-topic](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic); asking us to write the program for you, suggestions, and external links are off-topic.

Comment: Ahh... don't do it.. Just sum the data whenever you need it. Databases are great at adding up, and it means you don't have to faff about keeping it in sync

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not understandable. You also need to share sample data and table structure. And even the result you want.

```
create table order_(
  order_id int PRIMARY KEY,
  sum_price int
 );
create table order_position(
  order_id int,
  price int
 );
 
 insert into order_position values (1,10),(1,15),(2,20),(1,18),(2,10),(1,12),(2,8);
insert into order_ values (1,0),(2,0);
```

This query:

```
update order set sum_price = 0;
Update order_ o 
left join (select order_id, sum(price) as sum_p from order_position group by order_id) op on op.order_id = o.order_id
set o.sum_price = sum_p;

Select * from order_;
Select * from order_position;
```

I made a test with my own data. I hope it works for you.